# Fix an unknown bug, copy all the code or give a link?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, hyperlinks, code, rules

I am gradually starting to learn all the publishing rules in Stack Overflow.

I understood that it was necessary to publish as much explanation as possible by publishing this code without putting only a link from the web page on which the code is, and with a snippet of code as short as possible.

But I wonder, when we do not know the bug of a web page that we create, that we do not know where the problem comes from.

Is it better to copy a big part of my CSS, HTML and JavaScript code or should we post a link to this website instead?

Comment: Relevant: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"copy the entire Css, Html and javascript codes or should we post a link to this website instead"* .. neither, you're still obliged to create a minimal, reproducible example (see the link posted by Jeanne). When you yet don't know where the issue is coming from, then you need to start digging in your code. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service to do that for you.

Comment: I already see the link posted by Jeanne, and i make a mistake in my question, 
I meant to copy "a big part of my code" rather than "all my code" (edited). I understand now that it's better to don't post a question if I don't know where the error in my web page comes from, but just post on specific problems.

Comment: If, hypothetically, you cannot reduce the amount of code required to an amount appropriate to post, it might indicate that your question is not suitable for the site. Linking to code hosted elsewhere is not appropriate.

Comment: See also [Jon Skeet's (relatively) short checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It includes *"If your question includes code, have you written it as a short but complete program?"*.